# Delete first line in XML file in Java if empty

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I receive a file from a server with my university schedule and trying to extract data from it. In some files (for some departments) there's a blank line on the top and it's the first line of the file, so I get:

`[Fatal Error] lesson:2:6: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.`

How can I check for the blank line and delete it in the same file in Java? I couldn't get anything done with strings and lines as XML files usually don't have `\n` on the end of the line.

UPD

```
//it appeared on knt/151 file, so empty lines in the beginning of the file that caused fatal error
private void checkForEmptyLines(File f) {
    try {
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f,"rw");
        while (raf.getFilePointer()!=raf.length()){
           //What should be here?
           Byte b = raf.readByte();
           if (b!=10)
               raf.write(b);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

UPD xml file handling:

```
public String[][] parse(String path)  {
    String[][] table = new String[8][6];

    File data = new File(path);
   // checkForEmptyLines(data);

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder  = null;
    Document doc = null;

    try {
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = dBuilder.parse(data);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Data");

    int rowIndex = 0;
    int columnIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
        if (i > 7 && !((i - 14) % 7 == 0)) { 
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            String line = node.getTextContent().replaceAll("\\t+", " "); 
            line = line.replace("\n", " ");

            if (columnIndex >= 6) {
                columnIndex = 0;
                ++rowIndex;
            }

            table[rowIndex][columnIndex++] = line;
        }
    }
```

XML file [example](http://pastebin.com/W5vmsULC)

Comment: show how you are reading the file..

Comment: show your code please

Comment: I doubt the blank line is causing the error.

Comment: @bohemian but if i don"t use this method and delete first blank line, I get everything done. I'll attach XML handling a bit later today

Comment: Post a segment of the file

Comment: @hd1 xml file segment?

Comment: @Bohemian added xml file handling code

Comment: The XML you're trying to parse, post a sample of that

Comment: @hd1 added as link to pastebin

Comment: My validator's giving me invalid because of the first line, if I remove that, I get no further errors. Let me work with your code for a minute and I'll post a solution

Answer (score 0):

There is no quick and simple answer to this but suffice it to say you should see about treating the input as a stream.  I have updated your "check for empty lines" method to essentially advance a stream until it reaches the first '<' character then resets the stream and hands off processing

```
//it appeared on knt/151 file, so empty lines in the beginning of the file that caused fatal error
private void checkForEmptyLines(BufferedInputStream fs) throws IOException {
    // Set mark and allow for up to 1024 characters to be read before this mark becomes invalid
    fs.mark(1024);
    int ch;
    while( -1 != (ch = fs.read()) {
        if( '<' == ch ) {
            fs.reset();
            break;
        }
        else {
            fs.mark(1024);
        }
    }
}

public String[][] parse(String path)  {
    String[][] table = new String[8][6];

    File data = new File(path);
    FileInputStream dataStream= new FileInputStream(data);
    BufferedInputStream bufferedDataStream= new BufferedDataStream(dataStream, 1024);
    checkForEmptyLines(bufferedDataStream);

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder  = null;
    Document doc = null;

    try {
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = dBuilder.parse(bufferedDataStream);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Data");

    int rowIndex = 0;
    int columnIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
        if (i > 7 && !((i - 14) % 7 == 0)) { 
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            String line = node.getTextContent().replaceAll("\\t+", " "); 
            line = line.replace("\n", " ");

            if (columnIndex >= 6) {
                columnIndex = 0;
                ++rowIndex;
            }

            table[rowIndex][columnIndex++] = line;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My colleague has added this code and it seems that it works. It not only checks for an empty string in the beginning, but also deletes it and writes correct data to a new file.

This solution seems to be slow, if any improvements can be done, please tell me.

```
private static File skipFirstLine(File inputFile) {
    File outputFile = new File("skipped_" + inputFile.getName());

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
         BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile))) {

        String line;
        int count = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (count == 0 && line.equals("")) {
                ++count;
                continue;
            }

            writer.write(line);
            writer.write("\n");
            ++count;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return outputFile;
}
```

Comment: I would use `line.trim().isEmpty())`. Your code would fail if the first line included even one space character.